# How can I wrap the current directory in strings in CMD?

Tags: cmd, echo, cd

I need to write a command which will change the current directory and print the NEW directory wrapped in some tags. I thought `cd SOMEPATH & echo wkd%cd%wkd` would do it but there is a problem.

Here is some example input and output

```
C:\Users> cd .. & echo wkd%cd%wkd
wkdC:\Userswkd
```

As you can see, the OLD directory was printed. Why does this happen?
I also tried using newlines (since I feed the command though an external program) but that gives problems when starting command line software.

I really hope there is a solution for this.

Comment: I know why it happens: the %cd% environment variable is set before any of the command executes and is not changed until the interpreter goes on to the next command entirely. It treats foo & bar as a single command with two parts. I don't know how to fix it yet though...

Comment: ON Linux, I would just do wkd`cd`wkd. Windows doesn't quite do that but it sort of does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130768/put-command-output-into-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch files, lines or blocks of code (code enclosed in parenthesis) are first parsed, then executed and the process repeated on the next line/block. During the parse phase all read operations to obtain a value from a variable are removed from the code, replaced with the value in the variable before starting to execute the code.

In your case, when the line is parsed `%cd%` is replaced with its value before starting to execute the line and change the folder.

Alternatives:

- If you separate the command in two lines you will retrieve the correct value.

```
    cd ..  
    echo wkd%cd%wkd
```

- You can enable delayed expansion and change the syntax used to retrieve the variable from `%var%` to `!var!` telling the parser the read operation should be delayed until the execution time

```
    rem inside a batch file
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cd .. & echo wkd!cd!wkd

    rem from a command line
    cmd /v:on /q /c "cd .. & echo wkd!cd!wkd"
```

- You can escape the percent signs to the parser does not see a variable and force a command reevaluation before the `echo` to get the correct value. You can do it with a `call` command. It works, but `call` is slower than other options

```
    rem inside a batch file
    cd .. & call echo wkd%%cd%%wkd

    rem from command line
    cd .. & call echo wkd^%cd^%wkd
```

- Instead of reading a variable, you can execute a command that retrieve the required information

```
    rem from command line
    cd .. & for %A in (.) do echo wkd%~fAwkd
    cd .. & for /f %A in ('cd') do echo wkd%Awkd

    rem in batch files the percent sign needs to be escaped
    cd .. & for %%A in (.) do echo wkd%%~fAwkd
    cd .. & for /f %%A in ('cd') do echo wkd%%Awkd
```

(`%~fA` is the full name of the element referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%A`)

There is a difference in how `for /f` and `for` commands in previous code work

- `for /f` is starting a `cmd` instance that will execute the `cd` command to output the current directory, output that is processed by the code in the `do` clause that is invoked for each output line, with the line stored in the replaceable parameter
- `for` without modifiers directly retrieves a reference to the element indicated, in this case `.`, the current folder. In this case `%~fA` is used to obtain a real full name from the relative `.` reference into an absolute path

All this options are only doing one thing: delay the retrieval of the current folder until the `cd ..` has been executed.

Comment: Thanks! These did the charm

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
cd .. & For /F %A in ('cd') do echo wkd%Awkd
```

The for loop thing does command output capture as found here: [Put command output into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130768/put-command-output-into-a-variable)

Then I just echo that variable with the stuff around it.

The reason why your original try didn't work is that the %cd% environment variable is set before any of the command executes and is not changed until the interpreter goes on to the next command entirely. It treats foo & bar as a single command with two parts.