# How to put the output command in a windows batch variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I need to put the content of a command inside a variable
The command is

```
findstr dftFileName test
```

but the output of this batch is the command itself

```
set one=findstr dftFileName test
echo %one%
```

Comment: This is batch not bash. To get the output of a command you need a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f) A variable in batch can hold only one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put command output into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130768/put-command-output-into-a-variable)